# Cloning string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, memory, clone

### My question is: how's work cloning in **ruby**?

### When exactly does cloning happen?

---

So, all I have are function **cur_memory**, which returns current used memory in **Gb** , string **s1** that contain long text and **s2** that is cloned of prev:

```
def cur_memory
  %x(free).split("\n")[1].split(' ')[2].to_f / 10**6
end
```

**Pay attention, it takes 3 gigabytes of memory!** *(or you can replace 9 by 8 below)*

```
m = cur_memory              # snapshot
s1 = '0'*10**9              # create long string

p (cur_memory - m).round 3  # 1st output
s2 = s1.clone
p (cur_memory - m).round 3  # 2nd output
s1[0] = '2'
p (cur_memory - m).round 3  # 3rd output
s2[0] = '1'
p (cur_memory - m).round 3  # 4th output
```

**output:**

```
0.978
0.978
1.957
2.936
```

---

1. First output is okay!
2. Why nothing changed after 1st output?
3. Okay, maybe ruby smart, maybe it's sort of lazy cloning. *(but anyway, I would like to know)*
4. **But WTF now? 3 gigabytes instead of 2?**

---

**P.S. Tested on Ruby 2.1.0 and 2.4.0**

Comment: `free` is linux only. My guess is that it more 'lazy releasing' GC (at least on Python) is not instant.

Comment: even though it's linux thing, why I lose 3 gb instead of 2?

I look to **System Monitor** and it confirmed losing.

Comment: "why I lose 3 gb instead of 2" – Allocating memory is expensive. The memory manager may have decided that, since you allocated a large block of memory just recently, it is likely that you would allocate another large block soon and thus decided to pre-allocate some memory to avoid a future allocation.

Comment: I understood you idea

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in MRI 2.4 and JRuby 9.1.2 on MacOS X. In both, MRI and JRuby I found that they behave similarly when run as a script. The memory is allocated for the clone when either the original or copy is modified, i.e. they no longer match each other.

```
def cur_memory
  pid = Process.pid
  `ps -p#{pid} -o rss=`.to_f / 1024
end

def diff(m)
  (cur_memory - m).round 3
end

m = cur_memory              # snapshot

s1 = '0'*10**8              # create long string
p "1st output #{diff(m)} MB"

s2 = s1.clone
p "2nd output #{diff(m)} MB"

s2[0] = '2'
p "3rd output #{diff(m)} MB"

s1[0] = '1'
p "4th output #{diff(m)} MB"

s2[0] = '1'
p "5th output #{diff(m)} MB"

s1[0] = '2'
p "6th output #{diff(m)} MB"
```

Output:

```
"1st output 95.379 MB"
"2nd output 95.41 MB"
"3rd output 190.781 MB"
"4th output 286.152 MB"
"5th output 286.152 MB"
"6th output 286.152 MB"
```

In JRuby, we can observe how the heap memory is allocated. It shows that once the clone is allocated modifications do not increase the heap usage.

```
require 'java'

java_import 'java.lang.System'
java_import 'java.lang.management.ManagementFactory'

def cur_heap
  ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage.getUsed.to_f / (1024 * 1024)
end

def cur_memory
  pid = Process.pid
  `ps -p#{pid} -o rss=`.to_f / 1024
end

def diff_mem(m)
  (cur_memory - m).round 3
end

def diff_heap(m)
  (cur_heap - m).round 3
end

System.gc
m = cur_memory              # snapshot
h = cur_heap

s1 = '0'*10**8              # create long string
System.gc
p "1st output #{diff_heap(h)}/#{diff_mem(m)} MB"

s2 = s1.clone
System.gc
p "2nd output #{diff_heap(h)}/#{diff_mem(m)} MB"

s2[0] = '2'
System.gc
p "3rd output #{diff_heap(h)}/#{diff_mem(m)} MB"

s1[0] = '1'
System.gc
p "4th output #{diff_heap(h)}/#{diff_mem(m)} MB"

s2[0] = '1'
System.gc
p "5th output #{diff_heap(h)}/#{diff_mem(m)} MB"

s1[0] = '2'
System.gc
p "6th output #{diff_heap(h)}/#{diff_mem(m)} MB"
```

Output:

```
"1st output 95.392/103.844 MB"
"2nd output 94.503/101.262 MB"
"3rd output 189.871/200.262 MB"
"4th output 189.876/299.277 MB"
"5th output 189.877/299.328 MB"
"6th output 189.878/299.41 MB"
```

Note: The MRI behavior is slightly different when using IRB. It shows increased memory usage as soon as the clone is created.

Comment: And Rubinius uses Ropes instead of Strings for its implementation of `String`, AFAIK, which would probably give yet another different behavior. The takeaway is: the Ruby Language Specification does *not* specify any particular implementation strategy for `String`s, and it does *not* specify any particular memory behavior for `String`s, therefore, the implementors are free to do what they want (and they *do* take advantage of that freedom), so one should not rely on that.